# DocuSign PowerForm text field to webhook

Tags: docusignapi

I have a PowerForm with a text field that is pre populated via URL. I can see the field’s contents when signing. But when I look at the data received by the webhook, the text field and its value are not sent. I am using webhook.site for testing. Your ideas are welcome!

I’ve tried including the PowerForm in the webhook. Doesn’t make a difference either way. All I really want from the webhook is this one text field. I don’t even need the signer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a tab in a Connect publish, you'll need to go to the Include Data section and enable **both** Recipients and Tabs.